# override regional settings in a calculated column to use dot as decimal instead of comma in calculated column

Tags: 2010, regional-settings

My SP site's regional settings are set to Germany. In Germany a comma is used as the decimal point instead of a dot. So if I have a calculated column that shows the result of `50/100` it will print `0,5`. My calculated column function is more complex then that but I'm simplifying for the sake of this question.

Is there anyway I can override the regional settings to show a dot instead of a comma? So I'd want the output to be `0.5`?

Comment: Please do share your Calculated Formula.. *Vieleicht kan ich etwas andern* (poor attempt at writing german)

Comment: @DannyEngelman: "filter: alpha(opacity="&[opacity]&"); opacity: "&[opacity]/100&"; " and [opacity] is a number between 0 and 100.

Comment: You are creating HTML and use the datatype=Number trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint does **not** have a `SUBSTITUTE` (of multiple characters) like Excel has.

So you have to use the `REPLACE` function (which does **not** have the same syntax as Excel)

```
=REPLACE( n1 , FIND(",",n1) , 1 , "." )
```

If you want to do more Replacements you have to nest the statements (and SharePoint has a limitation of **7** nested statements...)

All tested and tried functions that work in SharePoint:
https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Thank you! But now I am wondering if different regions use different characters for decimal. I might have to do something else to make sure decimals always use a dot...

Comment: **commas and periods** are the only ones on this planet. So this Formula is save for all... Unless you have users on Delta-Centauri-7 .. legend has it they use ``0123456789`` as decimal separator (but they do not use a decimal notation.. its called DC-7 for a reason)

Comment: PS. If you mark [your questions](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/42332/imthenachoman) as answered they won't turn up in the un-answered list and you give answers some credit... tnx